# Mysql select distinct ID and name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with some fields. There's a problem with 2 fields.

Fields are `official_country_name_sort_field` that contain unique numbers and field "official_country_name" that contain names.

I want to select `official_country_name_sort_field` that is unique and use it in GET method, but on site I want to show names from `official_country_name`.

I have this function that show id's from `official_country_name_sort_field`:

```
$sql = "select distinct official_country_name_sort_field as name from t_container,t_country where  (t_container.country_id = t_country.id) and (t_container.category = '$category') and (t_country.slug = '$slug') order by t_container.official_country_name_sort_field";

   $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
   if (!$result) {
         $output = 'Error fetching official country names : '.mysqli_error($link);
         include   '../templates/db/error.html.php';
         exit();
    }
    $officialCountryNames = array();
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $officialCountryNames []  = $row['name'];

    }

    return $officialCountryNames;

}
```

```html
<?php foreach ($officialCountryNames as $officialCountryName ) : ?>
      <h3>  <a href="<?php echo "../currencylist?showall&country=$slug&category=$category&official_name=$officialCountryName"; ?>  "><?php  echo "$officialCountryName"; ?></a></h3>
      

      <?php endforeach  ?>
```

This show, where I have "officialCountryName" - ID's (numbers from table column "official_country_name_sort_field". How can I show names from table column "official_country_name" instead of ID's from "official_country_name_sort_field".

Comment: Add that field to your query.

Comment: I know this. This is how has been before. When I use "official_country_name" then I got names, but names are not unique. Some names are the same. This field "official_country_name_sort_field" has unique values (numbers). That is why I need to use it for selecting data, but I need to show names instead of numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql = "select distinct official_country_name_sort_field as code, official_country_name as name from t_container,t_country where  (t_container.country_id = t_country.id) and (t_container.category = '$category') and (t_country.slug = '$slug') order by t_container.official_country_name_sort_field";

   $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
   if (!$result) {
         $output = 'Error fetching official country names : '.mysqli_error($link);
         include   '../templates/db/error.html.php';
         exit();
    }
    $officialCountryNames = array();
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $officialCountryNames[]['name']  = $row['name'];
         $officialCountryNames[]['code']  = $row['name'];    
    }

    return $officialCountryNames;

}
```

Use above query and make change in while loop.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I changed it, but I got notice "Array to string conversion in ..."

Comment: When I change <?php  echo "$officialCountryName"; ?> to <?php echo $officialCountryName["name"]; ?> to <?php echo $officialCountryName["name"]; ?> then I got "Notice: Undefined index: name ..."